# ArgoCD Kernel Capabilities

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I'm still new to Kubernetes and trying to gain some expertise. I have a Cluster On-Prem and have been trying to setup CI/CD using ArgoCD. When I deploy the application, I get the below error message. Any ideas what this could be?

***deployments.apps "account-deployment" is forbidden: user "system:serviceaccount:argocd:argocd-application-controller" is not an admin and does not have permissions to use extra kernel capabilities for resource account-deployment***

Comment: saw [this one](https://gitter.im/ovh/kubernetes?at=5d78d9156e889c4bbdd8e3fd)? give your output for `kubectl -n argocd get serviceaccount argocd-application-controller`, `kubectl describe clusterrole argocd-application-controller`,`kubectl describe clusterrolebinding argocd-application-controller`

Answer (score 1):

The argocd service account, which are permissions set to a pod over the cluster API's is lacking permissions cluster-wide, take a look at roles, cluster roles, and role bindings, which is a way to bind permissions to a user/service account
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/

Comment: I gave the respective service account "argocd-application-controller" a cluster admin role. Even that didn't help.

    ```kubectl create rolebinding default-view \
    >   --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
    >   --serviceaccount=argocd:argocd-application-controller \
    >   --namespace=argocd```

This only happens when I provide SYS_PTRACE in the security context of the pod manifest.